# Linear Algebra - Finding a basis w.r.t which the matrix of a mapping is a Jordan Block

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $U$ be the complex vector space of polynomials in $\Bbb C$[$x$] of degree at most 6.

Define $D, T$ $:$ $U$ $\rightarrow$ $U$ by $D(f)$ $=$ $f'$ (derivative) and $T$ $=$ $D^2$ $+$ $D^3$.

Put 
$$ \begin{array}{rcl} V & = &  \operatorname{Span} \{ T^n x^6  : n \ge 0 \}\,, \\ W & = & \operatorname{Span} \{ T^n x^5 : n \ge 0 \} \,. \end{array} $$

Find a basis of $V$ with respect to which the matrix of $T|_V$ is a Jordan Block.

Likewise for $W$.

Please can anyone lend a hand here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid factorials, let us set $p_i(x) := \frac{x^i}{i!}$ and $p_{i}(x) := 0$ for $i < 0$. Then $(p_0,\dots,p_6)$ is a basis of $U = \mathbb{C}_{\leq 6}[x]$ and $D(p_i) = p_{i-1}$. Then

$$ T^0(p_i) = p_i, \\
T(p_i) = D^2(p_i) + D^3(p_i) = p_{i-2} + p_{i-3}, \\
T^2(p_i) = T(p_{i-2}) + T(p_{i-3}) = p_{i-4} + 2p_{i-5} + p_{i-6}, \\
T^3(p_i) = p_{i-6}, \\
T^4(p_i) = 0. $$

Hence,

$$ V = \operatorname{Span} \{ T^n(p_6) \, | \, n \geq 0 \} = \operatorname{Span} \{ p_6, T(p_6), T^2(p_6), T^3(p_6) \} \\=\operatorname{Span} \{ p_6, p_4 + p_3, p_2 + 2p_1 + p_0, p_0 \}. $$

Note that the degrees of the polynomials in the spanning set for $V$ we described above are decreasing so this is a linearly independent set. Hence $(T^3(p_6), T^2(p_6), T(p_6), p_6)$ is a Jordan basis for $T|_{V}$ with respect to which $T|_V$ is represented by the Jordan matrix

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0. \end{pmatrix}. $$

Comment: How would I use this to deduce the JNF for $T$?

Comment: @D.Stewart: Using similar arguments, try and calculate the Jordan form of $T|_{W}$. Since $U = V \oplus W$ where both $V,W$ are $T$-invariant, the Jordan form of $T$ can be easily deduced from the Jordan form of $T|_{V}$ and $T|_{W}$.